# Setting up docker-compose to watch for changes with multi-package golang project

Tags: docker, go

I am using a [standard structure](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout) for my go application.

It is built like this:

```
cmd
  app
    main.go
internal
  app
    server.go
  pkg
    users
      ...
pkg
  dependency
    ...
web
  app
    ...
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
```

The problem however is that with this structure it's very hard to mount and build the application dependencies. For example, it I use a file watcher such as [fresh](https://github.com/pilu/fresh), it only watches a single directory and runs a particular file. If I update say `pkg/dependency`, it will not see those changes.

docker-compose looks like:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  core:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - memcached
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      APP_ENV: dev
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/github.com/me/app
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  memcached:
    image: memcached
    ports:
      - 11211:11211
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.10.0

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/me/app

COPY . .

RUN go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
RUN dep ensure

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/me/app/cmd/app/
RUN go install
RUN go get github.com/pilu/fresh

CMD ["fresh"]
```

Any help?

Comment: what happens when you give your existing file change monitor tool the parent dir of all of above code dirs ?

Comment: It says no runnable go files are found

Comment: I think I might have to write something that basically looks at each package, and on change, reinstalls the package and then restarts the server...

Answer (score 1):

I would push back to that `fresh` repo and ask them

If your file changes are getting saved to git then you could setup a [webhook like https://github.com/adnanh/webhook](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook)  to listen to these `git push` actions to trigger your rebuild

However if they are just edits then you could roll your own using something like

https://github.com/hpcloud/tail

to do the functional equivalent to a `tail -f` on an arbitrary set of files/dirs which I have found to work nicely (my logs trigger a parse daemon for error checking)

but you're right there might be an easier way given your use case

Comment: Thank you. Im going to checkout both of those links. I might end up using something generic - doesn't have to be go and I'm guessing some other language perhaps has solved this problem.